# Is nosql a right tool for multy level forum like comment system?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql

I want to build a web app similar to Reddit.com, where you have multy level of comments, lots of reads and writes. I was wondering if nosql and mongoDB in particular is the right tool for this?

Comment: @Sentinel, Can you direct me to one that shows multi level comments? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431570/when-to-use-nosql-and-which-one

Answer (score 2):

Comments -- it's really thing for nosql database, no doubt. You avoiding multiple joins to itself. And it's means that your system can scale out!

With mongodb you can store all hierarchy within one document. Some peoples can say that here will be problems with atomic updates, but i guess that it's not a problem because of you can load and save back entire comments tree. In any way you can easy redesign your system later to support atomic updates and avoid issues with concurrency.

Comment: Do you know of any food tutorials or guides on how to do this? I can not wrap my head around how I would go about doing any of this without joins. Lets say I have User collection and Comments collection. If I update user, how does user information get updated in comments collections?

Comment: @user720943: Take a look here -> http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/3f35c3fb28891b52 for example.

Comment: Why don't write the system with atomic updates from the beginning?

Comment: @yi_H: Because with schema that support atomic updates you should perform additional operations to build hierachical data on the client side before display it.

Comment: You can store all the comments in one document and still be atomic.

Comment: No, you can't  Because for now mongodb does not supporting updates of multi level embedded arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit itself uses Cassandra.  If you want something  "similar to reddit.com," maybe you should look at their source -- https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki.

Here's what David King (ketralnis) [said earlier this year](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/the_apache_software_foundation_announces9) about the Cassandra 0.7 release: "Running any large website is a constant race between scaling your user base and scaling your infrastructure to support it.  Our traffic more than tripled this year, and the transparent scalability afforded to us by Apache Cassandra is in large part what allowed us to do it on our limited resources. Cassandra v0.7 represents the real-life operations lessons learned from installations like ours and provides further features like column expiration that allow us to scale even more of our infrastructure."

However, Rick Branson [notes](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2686835) that Reddit doesn't take full advantage of Cassandra's features, so if you were to start from scratch, you'd want to do some things differently.